# Why apply() converts date objects to numeric objects?

Tags: r, apply

Why apply() converts my date objects to numeric before calling the user function?

```
apply(matrix(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-01-05"), 1)), 1, function(x) { return(class(x)) })
[1] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

And why as.Date() doesn't have the origin parameter set to "1970-01-01" by default?

```
> as.Date(apply(matrix(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-01-05"), 1)), 1, function(x) { return(x) }))
Error in as.Date.numeric(apply(matrix(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-01-05"),  : 
  'origin' must be supplied
> as.Date(apply(matrix(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-01-05"), 1)), 1, function(x) { return(x) }), origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2010-01-01" "2010-01-02" "2010-01-03" "2010-01-04" "2010-01-05"
```

Comment: Have you even looked on what `matrix(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-01-05"), 1))` gives you before inserting it into `apply` or `as.Date`? `matrix` can store only atomic vectors.

Comment: So how do I make apply() work with non-atomic object?

Comment: Though you should know that `apply` converts everything to a `matrix` either way. What is exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function `seq.Date` in the base package that will allow you to make a sequence for a Date object. But a matrix will still only take atomic vectors, so you will either just have to call `as.Date()` again whenever you need to use the Date, or just store it in a dataframe because that can hold "Date" class values.

As far as the default parameter for as.Date, I don't think it makes sense to have 1970 set as the default. What if people are analyzing data from before that date for whatever possible reason?

Comment: About the origin parameter, why as.Date() doesn't require an origin then? There could be code that explicitly define dates as as.numeric(as.Date("1960-01-01")). That could break when ported across systems.

Comment: `seq` is generic and you already used `seq.Date` when called it on `Date` class.